# Execute command on ranger selection?

Tags: ranger

I haven't found an advanced tutorial on `ranger` yet, so my question is: is it possible to execute a command on a selection of files in `ranger`?

If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is in `man ranger`:

> @
>
> Open the console with the content "shell %s", placing the cursor
>   before the " %s" so you can quickly run commands with the current
>   selection as the argument.

So,

1. highlight the files you want to work on with `Space`
2. type `@` to get to a command prompt which will be `:shell  %s` with the cursor positioned before `%s`
3. type the name of your command and press `Enter`
4. the command you specified will be executed with selected filenames as parameters

The man page also covers adding a pause to check command output:

> ```
> FLAGS
>
> There are some additional flags that can currently be used
> only in the "shell" command: (for example ":shell -w df")
>
>  p   Redirect output to the pager
>  s   Silent mode.  Output will be discarded.
>  w   Wait for an Enter-press when the process is done
> ```

Comment: Is there any output? I execute `:shell realpath %s`, but no output.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically get spaces and such escaped in the selected filenames that are passed? I can do it manually of course but it can get tedious.